# SyntaxError: missing argument list in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, syntax-error

This is the error but I am not able to pinpoint it. The query runs fint when run from phpmyadmin SQL console

```
var query = connection.query('Select distinct a.*, IFNULL(b.scannerid,'Not Available') AS `scannerid`, IFNULL(date(b.datetime),'Not Available') as datetime, IFNULL(b.status,'Absent') AS `status` from studentdetails a LEFT OUTER JOIN discovereddevices b ON a.bluetoothid = b.blueid and date (b.datetime) = CURRENT_DATE',function(err,rows)
```

The error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Attendance system/app.js:13:24)
```

The Javascript code:

```
exports.getattendance = function(req, res){

         req.getConnection(function(err,connection){  
                var query = connection.query('Select distinct a.*, 
            IFNULL(b.scannerid,'Not Available') AS `scannerid`, 
            IFNULL(date(b.datetime),'Not Available') as datetime, 
            IFNULL(b.status,'Absent') AS `status` from studentdetails a LEFT OUTER 
            JOIN discovereddevices b ON a.bluetoothid = b.blueid and date (b.datetime) 
            = CURRENT_DATE',function(err,rows)
                {
                    if(err)
                        console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
                    res.render('showreport',{page_title:"Attendance Report Generated",data:rows});

                 });

                 //console.log(query.sql);
            });

        };
```

Comment: look at the nested single

Comment: Problem area is quotes, escape i.e. `\'Not Available\'`

Comment: you can't break string with newlines line this. read about multiline strings in javascript

Comment: what is on line number 53 of vm.js?

Comment: As @dfsq said, you can't use newlines in a single quoted or double quoted string like that. You could use them if you used the new backtick style [template syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that ES2015 adds, or you would need to close each line with a closing quote and `+` to continue on the next line with another string. You could also end each line with a \ to continue the string on the next line, but that is not recommended as any invisible white-space after the \ will break it and lead to hard to diagnose errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong usage of Quotes
Try using the backtick (`)

Example:

```
exports.getattendance = function(req, res){

     req.getConnection(function(err,connection){  
            var query = connection.query(`Select distinct a.*, IFNULL(b.scannerid,'Not Available') AS 'scannerid', IFNULL(date(b.datetime),'Not Available') as datetime, IFNULL(b.status,'Absent') AS 'status' from studentdetails a LEFT OUTER JOIN discovereddevices b ON a.bluetoothid = b.blueid and date (b.datetime) = CURRENT_DATE()`,
            function(err,rows)
                if(err)
                    console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
                res.render('showreport',{page_title:"Attendance Report Generated",data:rows});

             });

             //console.log(query.sql);
        });

    };
```

Edit :

Also CURRENT_DATE() should be a function!

Comment: no luck! Still the error persists

Comment: @yuvasreekalaiselvan can u plz try edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfect!

Comment: @yuvasreekalaiselvan you can accept as answer & Upvote it :D